# mysql Query to get data from two tables when not exists in either table

Tags: mysql, sql, string, left-join, full-outer-join

I am trying to fetch data from 2 tables, Table A and Table B.
Table A has id , name , description.
Table B has name , details , sub_details.

There are total 10 records in A and 5 Records in B.

if I execute a query,

```
select a.id , a.name , b.details , b.sub_details 
from A a, B b 
where a.name = b.name and b.name like "%ABC%";
```

the result will be show the records which has `ABC` in `b.name` column and where the same is present in A table. Now the issue occurs when any of the table does not have the data, and in that case entire result is blank.

my question is , what query shall I execute if I want to get the results even if any of the table does not have the data ?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Barmar can u please write the query

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT a.id, b.name, b.details, b.sub_details
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON a.name = b.name
WHERE b.name like '%ABC%'
```

If there's no matching row in `a` this will show the row from `b` and `a.id = NULL`.

Comment: is that what he wants? I think he wants either table to have data

Comment: @GarrGodfrey That's kind of difficult if he specifically wants to match a name in `b.name`

Comment: i think looking for FULL JOIN, or in MySQL would need UNION

Comment: That's certainly possible, and maybe GMB's answer is what they want.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the results even if any of the table does not have the data

You are describing a `full join`. Unfortunately, MySQL does not support that. Assuming that `name` is a unique key in both tables, you can use `union all`  and aggregation:

```
select max(id) as id, name , max(details) as details , max(sub_details) as sub_details
from (
    select id, name, null as details, null as subdetails from a where name like '%ABC%'
    union all 
    select null, name, details, sub_details from b  where name like '%ABC%'
) t 
group by name
```